# Auto Sync the Sql server table to MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I need to auto sync some tables in SQL server(inside corporate network) to remote MySQL server. I wrote a script when it runs it copies the data from SQL server to remote MySQL server. Is there any other way alternate to scheduled script. I found some suggestions like triggers but I don't know whether trigger works in this situation.

Comment: i doubt that they recomended triggers with two different rdms. Workbench would create such a query with odbc because you have to convert for example boolean. but even then would you like to run that query every time a row updates or gets inserted

Comment: Yes. Can you please give more information about Workbench query or how to approach this problem?

Comment: When you are connected to adatabase you sekect Database--> Migration wizard and follow the steps